# Overflow Menu in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile-application

I'm working on an app where the Main Activity has an Overflow Menu, that has two option/items in it About and Help. What I want is a way that if I clicked on say About, a card would come up on the screen over the Main Activity (not hiding it completely, being translucent) to show some text. I have looked it up and I have seen people talking about 'Dialogue Boxes'. I don't want that because it doesn't look "Material Designed", so if there is any other way I could achieve it or if there's some way I could make the Dialogue Box look like a **"Card floating above the Main Activity"**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can assure you that dialogs are part of the material design, see https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-specs

But if you want to show more than very little information, I'd suggest you create an About activity.

Comment: Thank you. I'll get back to you if this works out. Because I spent nice amount of time in YouTube searching that thing but none of their Dialogue Box looked like the ones in the Link,so thought of posting here.

Comment: @Eugene H What are you talking about. That's official. The link provides all the guidelines.

Comment: @DeepakTalan I apologize, I thought you were talking about the application "Link" not this link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Material Dialog Library](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs)